# SELECT MYSQL record containing 2 possible values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to Select rows where a value is being returned. If they have chosen `Male` or `Female` in the select box, I would want it to search for that. That part is working fine. However, if they choose `Either`, I want it to say that MySQL should look if the column contains `Male` or `Female` and return any results.

Please note that I do not want to use OR statements inside the query if possible based on how the code is being written out.

I tried the below, but it did not seem to work. The values are coming from a select box in a form which has `Either`, `Male` or `Female`.

```
if ($postgender == "either")
{
    $male = "Male";
    $female = "Female";
    $postgenderuse = ($male || $female);
}
else {
    $postgenderuse = $postgender;
}

$query4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tennis WHERE gender='$postgenderuse' ORDER BY playerid DESC LIMIT 0,20");
```

Comment: what are all the options that the gender can be?

Comment: You want to do a logical OR without using `or`..? Why?

Comment: he doesn't need OR providing only two options are used for gender. If he want's to exclude "not specified" or anything else, he'll need to use OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start creating the query from statements, also check if the form is sending one of the 3 values (just to make sure)

```
if ($postgender == "Either")
{
    $postgenderuse = " ( `gender`='Male' OR `gender`='Female' ) ";
}
elseif ($postgender == "Male" || $postgender == "Female") {
    $postgenderuse = " `gender`='".$postgender."' ";
}
else {
    die('Error, no gender selected');
}

$query4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tennis` WHERE ".$postgenderuse." ORDER BY `playerid` DESC LIMIT 0,20");
```

Comment: Why store `"Male"` and `"Female"` in variable? You can just use them directly in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're treating gender in binary terms, as consisting of only two options (Male, Female):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tennis";

if(in_array($postgender, array("Male", "Female"))
{
     $sql .= " WHERE gender=".$postgender;
}

$sql .= " ORDER BY playerid DESC LIMIT 0,20)";
$query4 = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: and what if `$postgender` = `male); DROP TABLE tennis; --` ?

Answer (score 0):

if It is either, then change your query to do a wild card search.

> SELECT * FROM tennis WHERE gender LIKE '$postgenderuse'

That way, when they choose either, you can set postgenderuse to a % Sign.

Although, it might be a better idea to just use OR in your query, and build your query off of conditions, like:

```
if($postgender == "Male") {
   $condition = "WHERE gender='Male'";
} else if($postgender == "Female") {
   $condition = "WHERE gender='Female'";
} else {
   $condition = "";
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM tennis " . $condition . " ORDER BY BLAH";
```

In anycase, either way should work. Being able to construct queries from conditionals is part of the power of php.

~ Dan

Comment: This won't work for the `either` case. The query would become: `SELECT * FROM tennis WHERE ORDER BY BLAH`, which will throw an error. Beside where are `$Male` and `$Female` variables coming from?

Comment: Ooops, good spot - thanks I fixed that up. It is pseudo code, I guess if($Male) Should be if ($postGender == "Male"). sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have tried would work if you were using Bitwise instead of String for the field `gender`.

What I suggest, is to use the SQL [IN function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).
Something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tennis WHERE gender IN ('" + implode("', '", $postGenderArray) + "')";
```